# make wysiwyg as default

Tags: magento-1.9, wysiwyg

Insted of clicking the WYSIWYG Editor is it possible to make it visible without clicking ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open admin section, go to **`System -> Configuration -> Content Management`**.

In the **`"Enable WYSIWYG Editor"`** field you will see the available options for WYSIWYG editor:

> "Disabled by Default"
>
> "Disabled Completely"
>
> "Enabled by Default"

You can select **`Enabled by Default`**

[image]

**Note:**  This will enable the Show/Hide Editor toggle to be active by default when you are editing CMS pages and Static blocks. This setting does not effect the product editing screen.

If you want the WYSIWYG editor to open up automatically on page load for product editing (i.e. Short Description) you would need some custom javascript to 'click' the button on page load. This would be an edit to the admin panel js of Magento and would most likely not be recommended.

For more information refer : [How to Enable/Disable the WYSIWYG Editor in Magento](https://vimeo.com/130181563)

Comment: thankyou for fast reply but what i want is to change the textarea into WYSIWYG editor>

Comment: Which textarea? Custom?

Comment: Description * and Short Description *

Comment: Check this video : https://vimeo.com/130181563

Comment: ok thankyou. done watching and learned things.

Answer (score 1):

[@Rohit Kundale](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/34070/rohit-kundale)'s answer is correct for CMS content. However, you will need to apply the following hack for product content...

---

*Note: The answer to this question was originally posted here by [Nikitas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1091082/nikitas):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20307722/3254362*

*I am copying the answer here for simplicity...*

---

After a little research i found it.

1) Put this code in the .phtml file you want the editor to appear directly.

2) In the 6th line of the code you can see `elements: "short_description"`. You can change `"short_description"` with the element id you want. You can add more than one element id separated with comma and without spaces.

**Example:** I put this code in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit.phtml` because i want the editor to appear directly when i edit product's description, short description etc.

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function()
{
   tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "exact",
    elements: "short_description",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "inlinepopups,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,|,visualchars,nonbreaking",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_path_location : "bottom",
    extended_valid_elements : "a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]",
    theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : 'true',
    theme_advanced_resizing : 'true',
    apply_source_formatting : 'true',
    convert_urls : 'false',
    force_br_newlines : 'true',
    doctype : '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'

  });
};
</script>
```

Comment: ill try this. thank you for reply. ill guve feedback later.

Comment: Did that work for you?